# Set footer colour in xml

Tags: android, colors, footer, viewpagerindicator

I am using the ViewPageIndicator library in my app. I know I can change the footer colour by using something like .setFooterColor(Color.Red) in my code. My question was if I can set this in xml instead as I would like to to all the styling in xml.

Below is the xml code

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    />
```

What attribute do I need to set here to change the footer color? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for doing that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/tn.mkh.example.android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app:footerColor="#848484"
        app:selectedBold="true"
        app:selectedColor="@color/vpi_color_custom" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Good luck